# fitsSystemWindows on Fragment, Activity and DrawerLayout combination

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, windowinsets

## Problem

The activity layout has a `DrawerLayout` with a `FrameLayout` as content to `Fragment` and a `LinearLayout` to be opened and closed by drawer. The fragment used on content has a `FrameLayout` with `fitsSystemWindows` flag and a `Toolbar`.

If I insert the fragment at `onCreate()` all occurs as expected, the `FrameLayout` starts on position 0 and the `Toolbar` starts below the statusbar. But outside the `onCreate()` the same code fails, the `fitsSystemWindows` not works with `FrameLayout`.

An important point, I need the `Toolbar` and `fitsSystemWindows` flag on `Fragment` and not on `Activity`.

How to get the same behavior seen at `onCreate()` moment?

## Code

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        findViewById(R.id.item).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Out of onCreate fails
                replaceFragment();
            }
        });

        // With onCreate all OK
        replaceFragment();
    }

    private void replaceFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Main Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_gravity="">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="168dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#00ffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Click me"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                                                @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#0000ff"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Example

The `LinearLayout` to be opened is in red. The `FrameLayout` with the `fitsSystemWindows` flag is in green and the toolbar is in blue, the cyan view is working all the time, it need start at y position 0. The expected is Green and blue like the first time, but in the second time the blue is the unique viewed.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek unfortunately no. I did a workaraund getting the statusbar height and settong it as topmargin of toolbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the problem is, that the when the content is being changed, system will no longer dispatch those insets to the view hierarchy.

This can be easily solved with [`ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#requestApplyInsets(android.view.View)) API. That would force the system to dispatch `WindowInsets` once again.

> Ask that a new dispatch of `View.onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets)` be performed. This falls back to `View.requestFitSystemWindows()` where available.

So, in your example performing this changes would result in expected behavior:

```
    private void replaceFragment() {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.content, new MainFragment())
          // NOTE, we are performing `commitNow()` instead of ordinary `commit()`,
          // Because we want this commit to happen sychronously/immediately
          .commitNow();

      // Ask the framework to dispatch window insets once more to the root of your view hierarchy
      ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(findViewById(R.id.drawer));
    }
```

[image]