# Nested co-ordinate layout and fitsSystemWindows overlaps status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, windowinsets

Following is xml for my **Main activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/bottom_nav_view_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_view_icon_tint_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_view_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_assist_icon" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<include layout="@layout/navi_view_layout" />
```

Following is xml code for **Home fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.gmr.android.FixAppBarLayoutBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/card_dark_text"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAirportBg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/screen_bg"
            android:tint="#8a000000"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:title="@string/empty"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior=".view.ToolbarBackgroundAlphaBehavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:logo="@drawable/toolbar_logo"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
            app:theme="@style/TransperantToolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_recycler_slide_in"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="40dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Following is xml code for **Detail fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.gmr.android.FixAppBarLayoutBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/card_dark_text"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgStoreBg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/screen_bg"
            android:tint="#8a000000"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_behavior=".view.ToolbarBackgroundAlphaBehavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
            app:theme="@style/TransperantToolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_recycler_slide_in"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Now when I am calling **Detail Fragement** from **Home Fragment** my toolbar overlaps with status bar. If I call **Detail fragment** from any other fragment it is looking fine. **Also toolbar in Home fragment does not overlap with status bar although xml for *Home fragment* and *Detail fragment* is nearly the same.**

[image: Picture one shows when detail fragment is opened normally]

[image: Picture when detail fragment is opened from home page]

Picture one shows when detail fragment is opened normally

Picture two when detail fragment is opened from home page

**Latest update:**
This solution is helping me https://medium.com/google-developers/windows-insets-fragment-transitions-9024b239a436 but there are lots of changes involved any other short way to do it?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the behavior?

Comment: added screenshot plz check

Comment: Your activities should deal with the appbarlayout/coordinator layout. As for changing the toolbar from your fragment, you can simply do that by inflating a different menu.xml in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and updating them in `prepareOptionsMenu()`. You have the same code in two different xmls which you can just put in your activity's xml.

Comment: I want to keep toolbar in fragment as every fragment in my app has different toolbar layout so keeping it in fragment

Comment: You should include how you are opening your fragments. I would recommend you to add a fragment container inside your main_content layout and then load your fragments into that container using replace. Both of them should look the same if you are loading them into the same container.

Comment: make `fitWindowsSystem="false"` for everything but `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`. \n
Also,

Comment: make `layout_height="match_parent"` for everything but `AppBarLayout` and `Toobar` where it is `"wrap_content"`. this should work.

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms you mention are very similar to the ones, mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35799876/1083957) question. To recap from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055856/1083957) that I have provided there, the issue is, that window insets are being dispatched the first time fragment is being shown, but they are not being next time you are making a fragment transaction.

You have to manually ask for the window insets to be dispatched in order to receive correct system bar paddings:

```
    private void replaceFragment() {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.content, new DetailFragment())
          // NOTE, we are performing `commitNow()` instead of ordinary `commit()`,
          // Because we want this commit to happen sychronously/immediately
          .commitNow();

      // Ask the framework to dispatch window insets once more to the root of your view hierarchy
      ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(findViewById(R.id.root));
    }
```

Comment: This solution is helping me https://medium.com/google-developers/windows-insets-fragment-transitions-9024b239a436 but there are lots of changes involved any other short way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

***Design XML like this,***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/home_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/gray">

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgStoreBg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/screen_bg"
                android:tint="#8a000000"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_45sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_recycler_slide_in"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="40dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your JAVA file,

`onCreate` :

```
Window window = getWindow();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this in you detail fragment (just give it a try):

```
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:title="@string/empty"

            app:logo="@drawable/customimage"
```

and make one **image as transparent add it as customimage for detail**, this would be probably a trick.
Thank you.